# _utmz cookie isn't created for localhost

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, localhost

I've configured Google Universal Analytics for my website. The problem I'm having is that analytics.js cookies(_utma,_utmb,_utmc,_utmz) are created on my remote website (not localhost) and not created on localhost.

By create I mean that those cookies are present when I open my website on a dedicated server (www.mywebsite.com) and when I open localhost those cookies aren't shown.

How can I make them work on a localhost as well?

Answer (score 0):

Universal Analytics does not create utm cookies anywhere (instead it [creates a single _ga cookie that holds only the client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains)). So I guess your remote site has some "classic" analytics code left in it.

To make Universal Analytics  "work" on localhost you can set the cookie domain to "none".